# How can I rename object key using rxjs

Tags: rxjs, edit

I have a response from server and I need to rename two keys using rxjs.
The response is like that:

```
           {
        "transactionBusinessId": "280",
        "deviceId": "13",
        .
                .
                    .
        "chargeSessionLiveDataDto": [
            {
                "timeStamp": 1677851096,
                "value": 30.0
            },
            {
                "timeStamp": 1630704615,
                "value": 987654.0
            },
            {
                "timeStamp": 1677851055,
                "value": 30.0
            },
            {
                "timeStamp": 1677851089,
                "value": 30.0
            },
            {
                "timeStamp": 1630672215,
                "value": 1.0
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to rename 'timestamp' with 'x' and 'value' with 'y'. How can I reach that by saving the original structure?
Thank you all.

I don't know how long is chargeSessionLiveDataDto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an RxJs map operator to transform the emitted value and in the function you pass in to do the transformation you use the spread operator to map the value and a map on the array

```
obs$.pipe(
  map(res => ({
    ...res, 
    chargeSessionLiveDataDto: res.chargeSessionLiveDataDto.map(val => ({
      x: val.timeStamp, y: val.value
    }))
  }))
)
```

When you have an RxJs stream and you want to transform the values emitted by the stream that is always a map.

```
obs$.pipe(map(value => functionThatTransformsValue(value)));
```

When you have an object and you want to use the properties to construct a new object you use the spread operator.

```
const newObj = { ...obj };
```

if you want the new object to have properties with overwritten values

```
const newObj = { ...obj, prop: 'new value' };
```

if you want to transform an array of values into a new array where each item has been transformed you use the arrays map function

```
const newArray = array.map(value => functionThatTransformsValue(value));
```